# Shearing SCNPlane with ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, linear-algebra, arkit

I want to shear a `SCNPlane` like in the image below, but then on the Y-axis. So B and C are moved upwards instead of A and B to the right. I know there is a transform matrix needed to accomplish this, so I have tried to create this transform matrix like the code snippet below. But none of the possible options does give the desired result. Besides, the `SCNPlane` is rotated -90 around the X-axis. Maybe someone can show me what I'm doing wrong.

```
var transformMatrix = matrix_float4x4()
transformMatrix.columns.0 = [1.0, tan(60), 0.0, 0.0]
transformMatrix.columns.1 = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
transformMatrix.columns.2 = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
transformMatrix.columns.3 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

let newTransform = matrix_multiply(transformMatrix, simd_float4x4((transformPlane?.transform)!))
transformPlane?.simdTransform = newTransform
```

I got the transform matrix from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206220/3d-skew-transformation-matrix-along-one-coordinate-axis) question (number 3).

[image]

Comment: Not sure it’s related to the problem, but why convert from SIMD matrix to SceneKit matrix for a multiply only to convert back to SIMD?

Comment: @rickster I updated my question and code to your answer. This doesn't work neither, the plane is only rotating.